# Springdata MongoDB push at position do not set class

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I try to figureout why insert at position remove the `_class` making my find failling after.

I have an object:

HistoryItem

- field1
- field2

I have some child objects like:

SimpleHistoryItem extends HistoryItem

- field3

Then my class for document

```
@Document(collection = "history")
public class PersonnalHistory {

    /**
     * The ID correspond to the profile ID
     */
    @Id
    private String id;

    private List<HistoryItem> items;

    public String getProfileID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setProfileID(String profileID) {
        this.id = profileID;
    }

    public List<HistoryItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<HistoryItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

When I do a simple:

```
update.push(ITEMS, item);
```

The `_class` object is added. So when I do a find Mongo is able to map. I can find something like:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5856cec14781686ceeb34024"),
    "_class" : "com.bdproject.model.history.PersonnalHistory",
    "items" : [
            {
                "_class" : "com.bdproject.model.history.SimpleHistoryItem",
                "profileID" : "5856dcf347816870aab76137",
                "date" : ISODate("2017-01-08T09:20:27.363Z"),
            },
```

As I want to retrieve the more recent history item I need to do:

```
update.push(ITEMS).atPosition(0).each(item);
```

However when I am doing this `_class` disappears making my display failling.
I tried to tweek the system by putting in the HistoryItem:

```
private String _class;
public HistoryItem(Date date, HistoryItemType type){
    this.date = date;
    this.type = type;
    this._class =  this.getClass().getCanonicalName();
}
```

But `_class` is simply ignored and not set. :(

I also tried to do:

```
update.push(ITEMS).atPosition(0).value(item);
```

But the value is added at the end.
Do you maybe have an idea?

Comment: I've been watching https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1582 ticket. I think one workaroud will be to get all items and add/update new item in java and drop all the items for that doc and push all the items.

Comment: It is exactly what I do not want to do. If I have thousands of items it will be really costly it the end. I wanted to do this at display moment but really costly.